# Bash - print all seuqential lines from file and ignore non-sequential ones

Tags: linux, bash

I need to extract all sequential lines from a text file based on the sequence in the 4th column. This sequence is the current time, and there is only one entry for each second (so only one line). Sometimes in the file the sequence will break, because something has slowed down the script that creates it and it has skipped a second or two. As in the below example:

```
Thu Jun  8 14:17:31 CEST 2017 sync:1
Thu Jun  8 14:17:32 CEST 2017 sync:1
Thu Jun  8 14:17:33 CEST 2017 sync:1
Thu Jun  8 14:17:37 CEST 2017 sync:1 <--
Thu Jun  8 14:17:38 CEST 2017 sync:1
Thu Jun  8 14:17:39 CEST 2017 sync:1
Thu Jun  8 14:17:40 CEST 2017 sync:1
```

I need bash to ignore this line and continue without printing it, but still print everything before and after it. How should I go about that?

Comment: you'll have to show your own efforts to solve it... SO is about getting help with code you tried but got stuck...

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about the seconds field (eg, 14:17:39 -> 15:22:40 is clearly not sequential, but this code will think it is; if your data is sufficiently simple this may be fine):

```
awk 'NR==1 || $6 == (p + 1)%60 ; {p=$6}' FS=':\| *' input
```

To check the hour and minute, you could simply convert to seconds from midnight or add logic to compare the hours and minutes.  Something like:

```
awk '{s=$4 * 3600 + $5 * 60 + $6} NR==1 || s == (p + 1)%86400 ; {p=s}' FS=':\| *' input
```